# SortedList doesn't seem to be sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, collections, sortedlist

I made a wrapper class around SortedList. I add objects to this class expecting them to be automatically sorted alphabetically, but when I bind to a ListBox in WPF, I see then in unsorted order.

```
public class SortedObservableCollection<T> : ICollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged where T : INotifyPropertyChanged//, IComparable<T>
{
    private readonly SortedList<string,T> _innerSortedList;

    public SortedObservableCollection()
    {
        _innerSortedList = new SortedList<string, T>();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerSortedList.Add(item.ToString(), item);
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
        this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
    }

    void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerSortedList.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerSortedList.ContainsKey(item.ToString());
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _innerSortedList.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool success = _innerSortedList.Remove(item.ToString());
        if (success)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
            this.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item);
        }
        return success;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _innerSortedList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object item)
    {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            this.CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
}
```

To bind I simply do :

```
SortedObservableCollection<IRCUser> Users { get; private set; }
.. fill users...
lstUsers.ItemsSource = users;
```

Sample input :

```
5Muhammad0
2Muhammad1
5Muhammad2
```

The output also shows similar, with the ones beginning with 2, 4 etc riddled between the 5's.

Note: My `IRCUser` class did implement IComparable, but since I only want an alphabetical sort now I commented the implentation out hoping the default sorting would kick in.

NOTE 2: I have override the toString() method, which I forgot to mention :

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return (int)Type + Nick;
}
```

UPDATE :

It seems internally the `sortedList` maintains the right order, but it is not passed to the `ListBox` in the right order...

Comment: `(int)Type` is not a `string`, does your override compile?

Comment: since your `SortedList` key type is `string` you will get the default `IComparable<string>` implementation which is alphabetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly create the event object [NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This object has different overloads of constructor depending on the action. You must use the overload that uses the index of the new item when you create a new item:

```
new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item, index)
```

Here's quote from MSDN:

> Initializes a new instance of the NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   class that describes an Add or Remove change.

```
NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction, Object, Int32)
```

**UPDATE 0**

Also it is better not to use an overload of method `ToString` to compare items, and use the special `IComparer<TKey>` for this.
In your case, the correct code looks like this:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
    var key = item.ToString();
    _innerSortedList.Add(key, item);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, _innerSortedList.IndexOfKey(key)));
    item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged;
}

public bool Remove(T item)
{
    var indexOfKey = _innerSortedList.IndexOfKey(item.ToString());
    if (indexOfKey == -1)
        return false;
    _innerSortedList.RemoveAt(indexOfKey);
    item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
    this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item,
        indexOfKey));
    return true;
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return _innerSortedList.Values.GetEnumerator();
}

System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}

protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var handler = this.CollectionChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting your data on `item.ToString()` which may not be a very useful value to sort on.

Unless it is overridden, it will be the type name of the class and therefore the same for everything you add.

---

This obviously leads to the question, how should generic data be sorted. This is what [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) is for.

---

You'll note that there are several `SortedList<T>` [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.sortedlist.aspx) that allow you to pass an `IComparable` implementation to define your own order.

In any case, if you want to use the default `IComparable` implementation of string, you will need to use strings that differ in accordance with your desired order. Not type names that do not differ at all.

Comment: Yes I have overridden it to give alphabetical sortable value.

Comment: @MuhammadA, I don't see that in the question. Please show the relavent implementation of `IRCUser`, and the instantiation of `Users`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
_innerSortedList.Add(item.ToString(), item);
```

Let suppose if item is of type `Project.Test.CustomEntity` then `item.ToString()` will give you "`Project.Test.CustomEntity`" which is getting sorted by Entity's fullname and not by the value.

you need to write a custom sorter based on property selector of your T.

Have a look at this [article](http://elegantcode.com/2009/05/14/write-a-sortable-observablecollection-for-wpf/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but:

1) If the UI has a data template, and the sample output you showed there is not the result of IRCUser.ToString() - than, maybe, the ToString() does not provide a "good" hash value for sorting.

2) You may be better served by using a PagedCollectionView to wrap your collection, and set the ordering there.